# Windows Phone , Page Loading : Best Approach

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a situation where i need to load a page based on a condition :

The condition is

```
if( First time application is launched){

Load aggrement page;
}
else{

Load main Page;
}
```

What would be the best approach for this ?
Should i check the condition in the :

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Or in the main page before the initializeCOmponent() call ?

Comment: What is your question exactly? Where to put the code? Or how to check if it is a first launch? Or both? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

    if (settings.ContainsKey("isRanFirstTime"))
        //Navigate to page 1
    else
    {
        settings.Add("isRanFirstTime, 1);
        //Navigate to page 2
    }
}
```

About redirecting the navigation from App.xaml.cs find more information in the post from Peter Torr

[Redirecting an initial navigation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx)